# debugging dotnet core 2.0 project with monodevelop

Tags: debugging, mono, .net-core, monodevelop, breakpoints

I'm trying to debug my dotnet core 2.0 app on Monodevelop 7.4 on Linux centos. When I'm putting some breackpoints, monodevelop just goes through without stopping my app.

I tried some configs to enable it without success. Is it a bug ? or maybe it's not implemented in monodevelop yet?

Thanks in advance for your help.

David

Comment: Please switch to Visual Studio Code + C# extension. The .NET Core debugger is not open sourced, so I think it is not qualified as part of MonoDevelop.

Comment: As Lex Li has already mentioned, due to licensing restrictions currently with the .NET Core debugger, it is not available for MonoDevelop. Visual Studio Code on Linux is your best bet.

Comment: Thanks for your answers I will look forward to switch to visual studio code

Comment: Visual Studio Code is bullocks. Use JetBrains Rider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't expect that after a year it is me again to answer this question.

I just started an open source extension to hook Samsung's open source .NET Core debugger to MonoDevelop,

https://github.com/lextudio/monodevelop.netcoredbg